# Compilation error with tokio::run() and Send marker

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I am trying to build a library defining a generic datasource which can pull data from various sources, synchronously and asynchronously. 
When building the async piece, I ran into the following compilation issue which I don't understand how to address:

Here is my simplified code ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e9d9eddf267bb4a5e6f33f4ce7d42ff5&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

```
extern crate futures; // futures = "0.1.24"
extern crate tokio; // tokio = "0.1.8"
extern crate serde_json;

use futures::Future;
use serde_json::Value;

use std::collections::HashMap;

trait DataSource {
    type Data;

    fn read_async(&self, Option<HashMap<String, Value>>) -> Box<futures::Future<Item=Option<Self::Data>, Error=String>> 
        where Self::Data: 'static + Send;
}

struct DataSourceImpl;
impl DataSource for DataSourceImpl {
    type Data = Vec<String>;

    fn read_async(&self, _params: Option<HashMap<String, Value>>) -> Box<futures::Future<Item=Option<Self::Data>, Error=String>> 
        where Self::Data: 'static + Send 
    {
        Box::new(futures::future::ok(Some(vec!["some data".to_string()])))
    }

}

fn main() {
    let datasource = DataSourceImpl{};

    let params = HashMap::new();
    tokio::run(datasource.read_async(Some(params))
        .map(|content| {
            println!("Content read = {:?}", &content);
            ()
        })
        .map_err(|err| {
            println!("Error {}", &err);
            ()
        })
    );
}
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:45:13
   |
45 |     runtime.spawn(future);
   |             ^^^^^ `dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures::Map<std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>>, [closure@src/main.rs:34:14: 37:10]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures::MapErr<futures::Map<std::boxed::Box<dyn futures::Future<Item=std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>, Error=std::string::String>>, [closure@src/main.rs:34:14: 37:10]>, [closure@src/main.rs:38:18: 41:10]>`
```

Yet when looking into the standard library, I found the following implementations:

- `impl<T: ?Sized> Send for Box<T> where T: Send`
- `impl<T> Send for Option<T> where T: Send`
- `impl<T> Send for Vec<T> where T: Send`
- `impl Send for String`
- `impl Send for [failure::]Error`

What am I missing?

If I get rid of the trait and replace the `Box<Future<...>>` by `impl Future<...>` then it works ([playground link for the new code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e87d63c29317be57351e90f635f2993a&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)); yet I don't understand what is wrong with the trait & `Box` implementation...

```
extern crate failure;
extern crate futures; // futures = "0.1.24"
extern crate tokio; // tokio = "0.1.8"
extern crate serde_json;

use futures::Future;
use serde_json::Value;

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn read_async(_params: Option<HashMap<String, Value>>) -> impl futures::Future<Item=Option<Vec<String>>, Error=failure::Error> {
    futures::future::ok(Some(vec!["some data".to_string()]))
}

fn main() {
    let params = HashMap::new();
    let future = read_async(Some(params))
        .map(|content| {
            println!("Content read = {:?}", &content);
            ()
        })
        .map_err(|err| {
            println!("Error {}", &err);
            ()
        });

    tokio::run(future);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to change the function signature to

```
fn read_async(
    &self,
    _: Option<HashMap<String, Value>>,
) -> Box<Future<Item = Option<Self::Data>, Error = String> + Send> {
//                                                        ^^^^^^^
```

Indeed, `Box<T>` should be `Send` when `T` is `Send`, but I have to spell it out because `Future` doesn't derive it manually/automatically.

Thanks to [Tobz](https://github.com/tobz) for pointing this out.